# Java - List<Object> -> Get Maximum of one int field where second int field is less than 1000

Tags: java, algorithm

The title didn't make sense I know. Here's more detailed version :

Lets say I have :

```
public class Numbers{
   double x;
   int y;
}
```

and I have `List<Numbers>`. Now I need to get the best version of instances of this object and print this versions to console where sum of `x` is the biggest and sum of `y` is less than 1000.

**I know that `x` can't be bigger than `1` and less than `0.5`**

my bet is to sort `y` values and then try to get the possible solution from filtering `y` , but I can't figure it out , any help is appreciated.

so lets take this example :

```
Numbers instances :
x = 0.7 ; 0.65 ; 0.5 ; 0.9 ; 0.55 ; 0.5
y = 250 ; 350 ;  450 ; 550 ; 750 ;  950
```

the best solution here is -> where `numbers.get(0)` (x =  0.7 and y = 250) and `number.get(3)` (x = 0.9 and y = 550) . sum of `x` is `1.55` and sum of `y` is less than 1000;
Any other solution in this example either `x` is less than `1.55` or `y` is greater than `1000`

You can sum as many numbers as you want.
**Of Course I can just make nested `for loops` and get the answer like that but the whole point is to use as less loop as possible. So basically, get the best solution**

**Looks like this is the Knapsack Problem. Answer was provided by @Andrew McGuinness**

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for a couple (2) of value from the list x? What is `the best version of instances` of an object? You say you need `0.5<=x<=1`but you use an example where `x == 1.55`. Plus, what did you tried?

Comment: @jhamon the question is to get best solution of `Numbers` objects where - **sum of `x` is the greatest and of this greatest - sum of `y` shouldn't be more than 1000**

Comment: @Aaron yes , the first filtering is done -> **I sorted the `List` with ascending order of `y` and than put a simple `if` statement that `if (y > 1000) -> don't use that instances`** . the example I provided is already filtered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking at some kind of "[knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)" -- you want to find a set of instances bounded by a limit.

This is a hard problem to solve from scratch, but there is a lot of research on it and some libraries you could use. It comes under the general field of "Dynamic Programming"

edit: [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) is a library I have used for this, but not from Java

(Oh, and you need x to be a float or double, not an int)

Comment: Fixed the `double`, Thanks for the information, I'll look into it

Comment: Found the library I used once before (though through Ruby bindings not from Java) - GLPK

Comment: I just looked into it, this is the exact problem I have. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [linear optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem. You might try the [simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) for that.